# How change the position of boxes within a row plotmat diagram in R (diagram package)?

Tags: r, diagram

I made the following template for a mediation diagram in the diagram package (plotmat function). Now all the boxes are aligned with each other in a rectangle, however, I would like to change the position of the "c" box to make the alignment of the boxes look like the (super quick) sketch I added. I read through the documentation of the package but couldn't really find an argument that does this. Does anyone know if this is possible and if yes how it's done?

```
library(diagram)
data <- c(0, 0, "'4'",0,
          "'1'",0,  0, 0, 
          0,0,0,0,
          "'2'","'3'", "'5'" ,0)
M<- matrix (nrow=4, ncol=4, byrow = TRUE, data=data)
plot<- plotmat (M, pos=c(2,2), 
                name= c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 
                box.type = "rect", box.size = 0.15, box.prop=0.5,  curve=0, shadow.size = 0)
```

[image: a very quick doodle of the desired graph as it's hard to explain]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you there:

```r
library(diagram)

data <- c(0, 0, 0, 0,
          4, 0, 0, 0, 
          0, 1, 0, 0,
          5, 2, 3, 0)

M <- matrix (nrow=4, ncol=4, byrow = TRUE, data = data)

pos <- cbind (c(0.2, 0.45, 0.8, 0.8), c(0.2, 0.6, 0.6, 0.2))

plot <- plotmat(M, pos = pos, name = c("c", "a", "b", "d"),
              lwd = 1, box.lwd = 2, cex.txt = 0.8,
              box.size = 0.1, box.type = "rect", box.prop = 0.5, 
              curve = 0, shadow.size = 0)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly fine. I now also understood the logic of the "two-column matrix of element positions" referred to in the documentation. I'm just wondering why the order that R views the elements in changed- why is c) the third element in my original code, but the first item in yours?

Comment: The rectangles are plotted in order of the coordinates set out in `pos` which combines the `xy` vectors by column, whereas your matrix combines data points by row. I think!